# How to calculate isoline within triangle element?

Tags: geometry

I have the following triangle equation with the triangle nodes $(x,y)_{1},(x,y)_{2},(x,y)_{3}$  and each node has the value values $p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\in\mathbb{R}$

I want to find the iso-line for
$$ p_{1}+\lambda_{1}\left(p_{3}-p_{1}\right)+\lambda_{2}\left(p_{2}-p_{1}\right)=p_{0}$$
and the contraints
$$\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}>0\\\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}<1\\ \lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}<1$$

and need the start and end point of this line (start and end point should be on the edges of the triangle element)

I tried solving the equation for $\lambda_{1}$ and then put it into the constraints but I can't manage to get to the correct solution.
Can someone give me a hint how to calculate the points?

Answer (score 0):

Just solve
$$p_1 + \lambda_1 (p_3 - p_1) + \lambda_2 (p_2 - p_1) = p_0$$
for say $\lambda_2$, and you get
$$\lambda_2 = \lambda_1 \frac{p_1 - p_3}{p_2 - p_1} + \frac{p_0 - p_1}{p_2 - p_1} \tag{∗}\label{∗}$$

$\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3 = 1 - \lambda_1 - \lambda_2$ are the barycentric coordinates for the point in the triangle.  The perimeter of the triangle are $\lambda_1 = 0$, $\lambda_2 = 0$, and $\lambda_3 = 0$ (i.e. $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 0$).

For $\lambda_1 = 0$, we get $$\lambda_2 = \frac{p_0 - p_1}{p_2 - p_1} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

For $\lambda_2 = 0$, we get $$\lambda_1 = \frac{p_0 - p_1}{p_3 - p_1} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

For $\lambda_3 = 0$, we solve the system of two equations, $\eqref{∗}$ and $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$.  We get
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\lambda_1 &= \frac{p_0 - p_2}{p_3 - p_2} \\
\lambda_2 &= \frac{p_3 - p_0}{p_3 - p_2} \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{3}\label{3}$$

However, this should be obvious if you consider the Barycentric coordinate system, as the above just tell the barycentric coordinate at which the isoline intersects with that axis – the line parallel to a side of the triangle.

For example, for $\eqref{1}$, consider the case where $p_1 \lt p_0$ and $p_3 \gt p_0$; say, $p_1 = 0.5$, $p_0 = 1$ and $p_3 = 1.25 p_0$.  Then, $\lambda_1 = 2/3 = (1 - 0.5) / (1.25 - 0.5)$, i.e. $1$ splits $0.5$ to $1.25$ at the two thirds mark, at ratio $2:1$ ($1-0.5:1.25-1 = 0.5:0.25 = 2:1$).  Similarly for the two other barycentric coordinate axes.  (The only detail is that the third is $\lambda_3 = 1 - \lambda_1 - \lambda_2$, so to solve that we need a system of equations, where the second equation is always $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$, and we solve for both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ simultaneously.)

Among the solutions $\eqref{1}$, $\eqref{2}$, $\eqref{3}$, you need to discard the ones where $\lambda_1 < 0$, $\lambda_1 > 1$, $\lambda_2 < 0$, $\lambda_2 > 1$, or $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 > 1$, because they indicate intersections outside the actual triangle.

If you have two such solutions, then $\eqref{∗}$ will apply between those two solutions.  If you want the Cartesian coordinates for the line, just convert the two solutions to Cartesian coordinates, and construct the line between the two; it will describe exactly the same line as converting $\eqref{∗}$ into Cartesian coordinates, but simpler.